# binding the custom object list to datagrid in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<songs>
  <song sname="song1.mp3"/>
  <song sname="song2.mp3"/>
  <song sname="song3.mp3"/>
  <song sname="song4.mp3"/>
</songs>
```

XAML

```
<sdk:DataGrid 
            x:Name="DataGrid1" 
            Margin="0,60,0,0" 
            IsReadOnly="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            BorderBrush="DarkGreen" 
            BorderThickness="5" 
            CanUserSortColumns="True" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False">
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Binding Code

```
 void ParseXMLFile(string dataInXmlFile)
        {

            List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();

            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);
            songs = (from r in xmlDoc.Descendants("song")
                     select new Song
                     {
                         name = (string)r.Attribute("sname").Value
                     }).ToList();

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = songs;
        }
```

When the above code runs - the datagrid is empty.

While debugging i can see the object songs have 4 items.

the issue is it not binding properly - any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us the source of your `Song` class.

I suspect you've declared the `name` property as `internal`.  You need to to be `public` for it to work in a DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code part

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = songs;
```

with

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = songs;
```

While it looks stupid, this works for me